Runtime Issue After Embedding the Unity Library into XCode Project
I have an Simple Unity Project with just a Cube in front of camera and then built for iOS Platform on Simulator SDK with Universal Mode on Unity
Unity Version:  6000.0.31f1
XCODE version: 16.1(16B40)
Steps to Recreate:
Then followed the steps I have performed to integrate the Unity Library into NativeIOSApp

Created a Sample iOS Project on Xcode with Storyboard and Swift.
Created a new Workspace named Bridge and then added both the NativeIOSApp and the UnityIphone Project into it.
In UnityFramework added the Target Membership for Unityframework
In NativeIOSApp added the UnityFramework in the Embedded Framework section of Build Settings.
When I build and run the App. I am getting the Issue at runtime and Crashes.

Issue:

libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_once_wait.cold.1:
    0x10380add8 <+0>:  stp    x20, x21, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x10380addc <+4>:  adrp   x20, 6
    0x10380ade0 <+8>:  add    x20, x20, #0xaf0          ; "BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBDISPATCH: trying to lock recursively"
    0x10380ade4 <+12>: adrp   x21, 39
    0x10380ade8 <+16>: add    x21, x21, #0x1e8          ; gCRAnnotations
    0x10380adec <+20>: str    x20, [x21, #0x8]
    0x10380adf0 <+24>: ldp    x20, x21, [sp], #0x10
->  0x10380adf4 <+28>: brk    #0x1

Any help would be appreciated!. Thanks in Advance.

For Simulator SDK Remove the Link Binary with Libraries in Build Phases of NativeiOS Project.
